Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification - using same string for EF that worked for SqlClient
I am transitioning from code that uses Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore in .NET Core 8.0. I have a connection string that successfully connects to a local SQL Server Express database in the former. I am attempting to connect to the same database through Entity Framework.
I have already used the Scaffold-DbContext command in the Package Manager to generate database models. I have this new code inside the app, in the controller for a page:
using (var context = new MyDatabaseContext())
{
    var result = context.Users.Where(u => u.Email.Equals(useremail));
    Console.WriteLine(result.Count());
}

This code works fine if you remove the .Count() from result, it just prints out

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[MyWebApp.Models.User]

However, when .Count() is added (I assume because that causes it to actually need to query the database?), the following error shows up from that line:

ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

I know that this error is related to my connection string having some kind of error. But, as the title states, the exact same connection string worked fine with SqlClient. However, the string is now pulled from appsettings.json (previously it was just hardcoded in, bad practice, I know, placeholder code. But I have already resolved errors relating to it not recognizing where the string was in the "ConnectionStrings" list in appsettings, so I am pretty sure it is working with the correct string).
"Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=my_database_name;
 Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=False;Integrated Security=True;"

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with this connection string, or if there is something else this error could possibly mean. I have tried manually removing bits like Trusted_Connection=True and Encrypt=False but they have made no difference. I have also tried replacing Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS with Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS or Server=. or Server=localhost.
Edit: Yes, I have looked at this question (and others like it). I am using SQL Server 2022 Express, which is 10 years after the latest version on that post. I have already tried the closest solution suggested for SQL Server 2012 listed on that post, using the connection string of
"Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=my_database_name;Trusted_Connection=True;"

It does not change the error (I am using Windows authentication AKA Integrated Security so I am not using username/password fields for database login).
Edit 2: I have also tried not escaping the slash. The visual editor points out the invalid escape sequence \S, and when I try to run the app, something breaks in the WebApplicationBuilder, and I get an error

Unable to connect to web server 'https'. The web server is no longer running

So I believe the escape slash is necessary!

This question is similar to: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The double backslashes are only used for the C# string literal, so that you get one single backslash in the final string. If you're moving this to EF in a place that's not a C# string literal and maybe doesn't need that, you'll get odd results.

How are you injecting MyDatabaseContext in your controller?

@SoftwareDveloper The only use/mention of MyDatabaseContext in this controller is what is seen in my code snippet. Though it is using MyWebApp.Models; at the top, as "Models" is the folder containing the DB models. I thought it was correct because all variables were recognized in the code. Is there another way I should be injecting the context?

@perihelions: Ok, makes sense. Have you tried var result = context.Users.Where(u => u.Email.Equals(useremail)).ToList(); to get a count?

"starting at index 0" - That tells you where the problem is.  What's the first character of the connection string?

@SoftwareDveloper using .ToList() there gives the exact same error on that line as using Count() on the next line did. I believe the error is related to actually connecting to the database (rather than a syntax error with respect to how the results are examined).

@madreflection as you can see by looking at the post above, the start of the connection string is the S in Server. As far as I know this is the correct syntax, as it worked fine in the SqlConnection model. As I have also mentioned.

No, the post contains your presentation of the value. I'm asking you to set a breakpoint and look at [0] of that string. Based on what we're seeing here, it could be 'S', but it could also be '"'. Or it could be a hidden control character, a zero-width joiner, or anything else that we can't see in the post.

Maybe show the part how you get the connectionstring from your settings into the dbcontext.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#update-database. The connectionstring in your Update-Database defaults to the one specified in AddDbContext or OnConfiguring. The reason I was asking about your DbContext was if you had a hardcoded connectionstring somewhere in your code;

Normally, the Dbcontext MyDatabaseContext will contains the dbcontext option inside the option, you could set the connection string.
I suggest you could re-check your MyDatabaseContext.
public class ApplicationDbContext  :DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
 }

And make sure you have set the connectionstring well.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

Then inside the controller or else, you should use the dependency injection instead of directly new the dbcontext.
Like below:
public class HomeController : Controller
{


    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;


    public HomeController( ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext )
    {

        _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;

    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {

         var result =  _applicationDbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Email.Equals(useremail));
Console.WriteLine(result.Count());
        return View();
    }
 }

